# Help explaining a logical math statement

Tags: logic

All variables are part of $M$ which consists of airports.
The predicate $p(x, y)$ means "there's a direct flight from $x$ to $y$).

Explain the statements:

#1: $\forall x\forall y\exists z (p(x,z)\land p(z,y))$

#2: $\forall x\exists y\exists z(p(y,x)\land p(x,z))$

Thanks for any and all answers, asked prof. but he just had some vague explanation.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Explaining what the statements say, it's in the title.

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: No, but it's what people read before deciding to check out the issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement says that given any two airports (perhaps they are the same), there's an intermediate flight between them.

The second statement says that any airport acts as a pivot to some other airports.

Comment: Thanks, GitGud. Point taken. +1 by the way :)

Comment: @amWhy Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Statement 1 says you can get from anywhere to anywhere with *exactly* one stop.  Statement 2 says every airport occurs as the stop for some one-stop trip.  (To be precise, the "one-stop trip" could be a round trip.)

Note that Statement 1 implies Statement 2, because the two "anywheres" can be the same airport, which means that for each airport there is another airport for which you can make a round trip; Statement 2 now follows by letting the round trip start at the other airport.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement says that, for any two airports, there's a flight between passing through one intermediary airport.

The second statement says that between any two airports there's a direct flight and that there's an airport such that there's a direct flight this from the destination of the first flight.

Comment: There's only one "$\forall$" in the second statement.